# How to insert (push) a new object into a nested array using MongoDB C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

```
{
    "_id" : "",
    "Username" : "",
    "Points" : 0,
    "CompletedAchievements" : [],
    "ActiveAchievements" : [],
    "Kudos" : [],
    "Teams" : [],
    "UserType" : "Standard"
}
```

Here is my record I'd like to insert into.
I am trying to add the following object into the ActiveAchievements array.

```
{
    "_id": "my new id",
    "progress": 10
}
```

I wish to add this into the Active Achievements array which already exists on a record(which has a unique ID I can get it by) in my database. As well as more in the future.

How would I do this using the MongoDb.Driver? In C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there is collection called `users` with a document's `Username` as "John Doe", the following code will add `{ "_id": "my new id", "progress": 10 }` to the `ActiveAchievements` array field.

```
var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("users");
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("UserName", "John Doe");
var update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update
                                   .Push<BsonDocument>(
                                        "ActiveAchievements", 
                                        new BsonDocument("_id", "my new id").Add("progress", 10));
var result = collection.UpdateOne(filter, update);
Console.WriteLine(result.ModifiedCount); // should print 1, as one document is updated
```

*References:*

- [MongoDB .NET Driver Quick
  Tour](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.11/getting_started/quick_tour/),
  see the section **Updating Documents**
- [$push Array Update
  Operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/index.html)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, this helped a lot and solved my issue